# download file without knowing extension

Tags: php, file

I got a script to download a file:

```
public function getResponse($file)
{
    $response = new Response();

    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    var_dump($ext);

    //$file .= '.pdf';

    if (file_exists($file)) {

        $fp = fopen($file, "rb");
        $str = stream_get_contents($fp);
        fclose($fp);

        $response->headers->set('Content-Description','File Transfer');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding','binary');
        $response->headers->set('Expires','0');
        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','must-revalidate');
        $response->headers->set('Pragma','public');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Length',filesize($file));

        $response->setContent($str);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

but I have a problem, I have no extension on my var $file, the code works if I add the extension.
Is there a way to download the file guessing the extension ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function.

This will let you search for files by pattern. So something like:

```
$found = glob($file . ".*");
```

Realize that you could potentially have multiple matches, and you need to look at the returned array.

```
if(count($found) == 1) {
   // One file found. Life is good.
   $filename = $found[0];

} else if(count($found) > 1) {
   // Multiple files matched! Which one should we download? Zip them all up?

} else {
   // No files found
}
```